# Has anyone been able to get the suds soap library to work with the NetSuite WSDL?

Tags: python, soap, netsuite

Has anyone been able to get the suds soap library to work with the NetSuite WSDL? I get this error when I try to create a client.

```
from suds.client import Client

#url = 'http://mssoapinterop.org/asmx/simple.asmx?WSDL'
url = 'https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2009_2_0/netsuite.wsdl'
client = Client(url)
print client


Traceback (most recent call last):
client = Client(url)
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\client.py", line 112, in __init__
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\reader.py", line 152, in open
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\wsdl.py", line 158, in __init__
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\wsdl.py", line 207, in resolve
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\wsdl.py", line 662, in resolve
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\suds\wsdl.py", line 757, in resolvefaults
Exception: fault 'ExceededRecordCountFault' not defined in portType 'NetSuitePortType'
```

Comment: It looks like its not processing the imports in the WSDL. Have you confirmed suds works with external imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2010_2_0/netsuite.wsdl

I found that it was failing on a validation between this part:

```
<operation name="checkAsyncStatus">
    <input name="checkAsyncStatusRequest" message="tns:checkAsyncStatusRequest"/>
    <output name="checkAsyncStatusResponse" message="tns:checkAsyncStatusResponse"/>
    <fault name="InvalidSessionFault" message="tns:InvalidSessionFault"/>
    <fault name="InvalidCredentialsFault" message="tns:InvalidCredentialsFault"/>
    <fault name="ExceededRequestLimitFault" message="tns:ExceededRequestLimitFault"/> -- mismatch
    <fault name="UnexpectedErrorFault" message="tns:UnexpectedErrorFault"/>
    <fault name="AsyncFault" message="tns:AsyncFault"/>
</operation>
```

and this part:

```
<operation name="checkAsyncStatus">
    <soap:operation soapAction="checkAsyncStatus"/>
    <input name="checkAsyncStatusRequest">
        <soap:header message="tns:headers" part="passport" use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:headers" part="applicationInfo" use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:headers" part="partnerInfo" use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:headers" part="preferences" use="literal"/>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output name="checkAsyncStatusResponse">
        <soap:header message="tns:headers" part="documentInfo" use="literal"/>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
    <fault name="InvalidSessionFault">
        <soap:fault name="InvalidSessionFault" use="literal"/>
    </fault>
    <fault name="InvalidCredentialsFault">
        <soap:fault name="InvalidCredentialsFault" use="literal"/>
    </fault>
    <fault name="ExceededRequestLimitFault">
        <soap:fault name="ExceededRecordCountFault" use="literal"/> -- mismatch
    </fault>
    <fault name="UnexpectedErrorFault">
        <soap:fault name="UnexpectedErrorFault" use="literal"/>
    </fault>
    <fault name="AsyncFault">
        <soap:fault name="AsyncFault" use="literal"/>
    </fault>
</operation>
```

I changed this:

```
<fault name="ExceededRequestLimitFault">
    <soap:fault name="ExceededRecordCountFault" use="literal"/>
</fault>
```

to this:

```
<fault name="ExceededRequestLimitFault">
    <soap:fault name="ExceededRequestLimitFault" use="literal"/>
</fault>
```

The modification allows Suds to create the client. Like John mentioned, it does take forever to parse(more than two minutes). I haven't tried using checkAsyncStatus to see if it works.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, suds can connect to NetSuite, but it takes a long time to process the WSDL.

Here's some sample code:

```
# Open NetSuite Session
wsdlNetSuite = 'https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2010_1_0/netsuite.wsdl'
client = Client(wsdlNetSuite)

# Login
passport = client.factory.create('ns4:Passport')
passport.email = 'username@web.com'
passport.password = 'ABC123'
passport.account = 123
loginResponse = client.service.login(passport)
print 'Login Response: '
print loginResponse.status

# Get a record
recordRef = client.factory.create('ns4:RecordRef')
recordRef._internalId = 127842
recordRef._type = 'invoice'
record = client.service.get(recordRef)
print record
```

You might also need to try various combinations of Python and SUDS versions. It's not a particularly reliable library.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error with your syntax example. I'm using Python 2.7 and Suds 0.4. Are you using different versions?

Comment: The above example was working with Python 2.4.3 and SUDS 0.3.6. It took 2 minutes for the Client() call to return.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit late, but for the record I attach a way of how one can work with 
NetSuite SuiteTalk SOAP API using Python Zeep.

Example of NetSuite SOAP login with Python and Zeep followed by adding a customer.

```
# pip3 install zeep
from zeep import Client

WSDL_URL = 'https://webservices.sandbox.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2016_1_0/netsuite.wsdl'
NS_EMAIL = 'admin@example.com'
NS_PASSWORD = '*********'
NS_ROLE = '1111'
NS_ACCOUNT = '1111111'
NS_APPID = 'FFFFFFFF-FFFF-0000-0000-FFFFFFFFFFFF'


def login_client():
    client = Client(WSDL_URL)
    Passport = client.get_type('ns1:Passport')
    AppInfo = client.get_type('ns5:ApplicationInfo')
    passport = Passport(email=NS_EMAIL, password=NS_PASSWORD, account=NS_ACCOUNT)
    app_info = AppInfo(applicationId=NS_APPID)
    login = client.service.login(passport=passport,
                                 _soapheaders={'applicationInfo': app_info})
    print('Login Response: ', login.status)
    return client


# Example usage
client = login_client()

# add a customer
Customer = client.get_type('ns14:Customer')
customer = Customer(
    lastName='Joe',
    firstName='Bloggs',
    email='joe@example.com'
)
response = client.service.add(customer)
print(response)
```

See also: https://github.com/fmalina/python-netsuite

Comment: Noting that the link to the `python-netsuite` library is stale. Thank you for the example, however :)

Comment: Fixed the link.

Comment: The line `client = Client(WSDL_URL)` brings up a connection error so I changed the WSDL_URL to `https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2018_1_0/netsuite.wsdl` and it connects fine though it takes quite a few seconds but I guess thats just how it is. Then it breaks again on next line `Passport = client.get_type('ns1:Passport')`   with error `LookupError: No type 'Passport' in namespace urn:types.core_2018_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com` Are you able to provide an update?

Comment: Someone forked it and made a ton of updates to the lib, try the fork

Answer (score 1):

Though not the best way to do things, if you're desperate, you can keep trying different versions of their wsdl.  I was getting the same error message, so I kept trying until one worked.  I went in this order:

```
'https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2010_2_0/netsuite.wsdl'
'https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2010_1_0/netsuite.wsdl'
'https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2009_2_0/netsuite.wsdl'
'https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2009_1_0/netsuite.wsdl'
```

'https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2009_1_0/netsuite.wsdl' finally worked for me

EDIT:
Based on tponthieux's answer, I realize now that you can use the suds plugin feature to fix the wsdl (I would simply comment on his answer, but I don't have the reputation yet :( ):

```
import re

from suds.client import Client
from suds.plugin import DocumentPlugin

NetSuite_wsdl = 'https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2010_2_0/netsuite.wsdl'


class Fix_NS_wsdl(DocumentPlugin):
    bad_fault = re.compile(r"(ExceededRequestLimitFault)"
            r"(\">\s*<soap:fault name=\")(ExceededRecordCountFault)")

    def loaded(self, context):
        if context.url == NetSuite_wsdl:
            context.document = self.bad_fault.sub(r"\1\2\1", context.document)

client = Client(NetSuite_wsdl, plugins=[Fix_NS_wsdl()])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a one-off fix on a saved WSDL instead of doing the fix every time (which takes a while) here is a VIM substitution command that I used

```
:%s/RequestLimitFault">\n\t*<soap\:fault name=\"ExceededRecordCountFault/RequestLimitFault\"\>\r\t\t\t\t<soap\:fault name=\"Exce   ededRequestLimitFault/gc
```

This works on the [2010 Netsuite WSDL](https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2010_2_0/netsuite.wsdl) and also had to do it for the [2012 Netsuite WSDL](https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2012_1_0/netsuite.wsdl) (you think they would have fixed it after two years)