# Netsuite Webservices (Python) fault

Tags: python, suds, netsuite

This is my first question on SO.

I am a beginner to Netsuite. I see out of box only PHP and Java are supported. I personally dislike both. I would like to use Python. I have used SUDS a few times for other work and thought it was ok, but not great. For my first attempt at netsuite I used SUDS and tried to do the standard client = Client(wsdl). I am using the 2012 WSDL here.
https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2012_1_0/netsuite.wsdl

I cannot even import the file due to a problem in it. Saw posts here

[Has anyone been able to get the suds soap library to work with the NetSuite WSDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400216/has-anyone-been-able-to-get-the-the-suds-soap-library-to-work-with-the-netsuite).

However the file actually used is from 2010. I do not even get the error on that version with no modifications. I wish to use the 2012.1 version. I have tried all available solutions and none of them work. I would even use something other that SUDS,if someone can suggest a good solution.

The error I get out of box is

```
"fault '%s' not defined in portType '%s'" % (fault.name, self.type.name)
```

Exception: fault 'ExceededRecordCountFault' not defined in portType 'NetSuitePortType'

Comment: FTR check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40741022/90263

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is old(er) but I was at this same point a couple of months ago as well. I tried using Suds to connect to SuiteTalk and (probably because of my lack of SOAP experience) was getting nowhere at all. I did manage to connect at one point (I believe I was using a different library than Suds) but trying to determine which WSDL to use was a nightmare.

In any case. I gave up on the SuiteTalk approach and started writing a few restlet scripts. Python has very good support for http requests(personally I'm using the excellent 'requests' module):

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/#

I understand that there may be a good reason to use the SOAP protocol (I suppose it's a lot more 'enterprisey'), but for our purposes writing a corresponding restlet  for everything I want to do works beautifully. We're doing significant daily automation tasks this way. I recently rewrote my request code to use threads and Netsuite allows you to perform up to 40 simultaneous requests which makes an enormous difference when you're working with thousands of records

If you're still stuck with trying to use Python with SOAP, I'd suggest giving restlets a try.

Comment: How did you get the authorization working in Requests? I've used urllib with no issues, but I get a 401 response when using requests.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar errors until I rolled back the version of suds to 0.3.8, 0.3.9 was failing without any useful information.  With easy_install run `easy_install suds=="0.3.8"` and then retry your code.